# How to change my YouTube channel name?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

My channel:  https://www.youtube.com/user/CoryRMcC

See pictured.[image]

I've tried methods in various videos and in the Help section, but all that appears to change is how my name appears when commenting *on* videos, not the actual channel name itself (as pictured, and circled).

Getting quite frustrating, b/c I feel I am losing out on potential viewers / subs b/c this will not allow me to adjust to something more "themed" for my channel.

Answer (score 0):

If your channel is connected to Google+, you can change the channel name:

1. Sign in to your channel on YouTube.
2. Open the Guide [image] and click **My Channel**.
3. Point your cursor at your channel name section, and at the right side of this section, click the pencil icon [image: edit] > **Channel settings**.
4. Under Account Information, click **Change** next to your channel name.

> Note: Google+ supports changing your name up to three times in 90 days.
>   Keep this in mind if you decide to edit your name.

Answer (score 0):

From [Change your channel details - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964?hl=en)

> ## Change your channel details
>
> If you use the name and photo from your Google Account for your YouTube channel, you can [update this
> information at any time](https://aboutme.google.com/). Keep in mind
> this will change your name and photo across Google services.
>
> If you use a different name on your YouTube channel than the one you
> use for your Google Account, your channel is likely connected to a
> Google+ page. If so, your YouTube channel name and icon come from the
> connected Google+ page, and you’ll be redirected to Google+ when
> updating these items.
>
> ### Change your channel name
>
> **Before you start**: Make sure you [confirm your name](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657961) on YouTube or
> you won't be able to change your channel name. Keep in mind that
> Google+ supports changing your name only up to three times in 90 days.
> Learn more [about Google+
> names](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271).

Below is included only one case, for other case follow the link on the top of this answer.

> #### Computer
>
> 1. Sign in to your channel on YouTube.
> 2. Click Menu [image: Menu].
> 3. Select **My Channel**.
> 4. Point your cursor at your channel name and click **Edit** [image: edit].
> 5. Select **Channel settings**.
> 6. Under "Account information," select **Change** next to your channel name.